# Color Index Key

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, colors

So I'm a little new to VBA so thank you for all your help in advance. What I'm essentially trying to do is a Vlookup function based on the color key. I'm not at all familiar with how to do that within an if function but I'll try and list out the variables here.

I want to look through the range B2:038 (which have colors but no values) and if they have the same color index as a key I have within A40:A46, paste the value of the respective cell in the key.

```
A40's RGB= 0, 154, 61
A41's RGB= 146, 208, 80
A42's RGB= 255, 210, 0
A43's RGB = 227, 27, 35
A44's RGB= 191, 232, 255
A45's RGB= 200, 200, 200
A46 has no color
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it with a simple formula, but you can with a macro:

```
Sub PopulateArray()

   For i = 2 To 38
      For j = 2 To 15
         For k = 40 To 46
            If Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = Range("A" & k).Interior.Color Then
               Cells(i, j) = Range("A" & k).Text
               Exit For
            End If
         Next k
      Next j
   Next i

End Sub
```

When you execute this macro, you scan all the B2:O38 range, and test if its background color is equal to one of the A40:A46 range. If so, you trasfer the corresponding text found in the A40:A46 range into the current cell.

If you want to change the font color, substitute the word **Interior** with **Font**.

Comment: @JohnC if this worked perfectly, please [mark this as the correct answer.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)